# iOS app crashes when relaunched with inbox/achievements opened

Tags: bug, status-norepro, ios-app

- Launch the iOS app
- Open the inbox or achievements menu
- Close the app
- Do other things with your phone until the app has been sufficiently bumped out of ram (not sure exact mechanism, but, uh, you know, app has to relaunch rather than resume?)
- Launch SE app again
- (Verify the text of the menu fades in from white, to ensure it actually relaunched)
- Close the menu
- Crash!

<sub>1.2.2.203</sub>

Comment: No-repro in 1.2.2.203 on iPhone 5s with iOS 8.1 (jailbroken, can confirm app is no longer backgrounded with process list). What version of iOS are you using?

Comment: I'm running 8.2. It could be 8.2-specific since that's about when the problem started occurring

Comment:  This is a crash I've seen in the simulator but never on an actual device.  There accessibility API has a zombie reference to *something* when dismissing the view controller.

Comment: Thanks @Brian . Any additional information/data I can provide that would be of assistance? That newfangled log-sending link worth tapping?

Comment: Do you have any accessibility features turned on?  Does it not crash if you turn them off?  I already have the logs that come with the crash report.

Comment: @Brian not really. Guided Access is "on" but not enabled. Reachability is enabled, but that's on by default. Everything else in the accessibility settings is off.